# Cucumber - testing principals vs speed

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, cucumber

after reading many articles, in my understanding all Cucumber tests should be independent from each other and autonomous, so that are rules I follow when I am automating my web app tests.

Lets say I am testing web page that has multiple input fields.

Currently, for CRUD operations I have two types of scenarios:

```
Scenario: Check page display correct data
  Given: I populate DB with data
  When: I open the page
  Then: Page data should match with data from DB

Scenario: Update page data
  Given: I populate DB with data
  When: I open the page
  And: I update each field with some new data
  When: I press save button to save data
  Then: Page data should match with data from DB
```

So in this case I have two scenarios that check if data is displayed properly, and another one that updates data and check it as well, but because step that populates the database takes long (1-3 seconds) I was thinking, why not combine this two type of scenarios, into single one, greatly cutting execution time:

```
Scenario: Update page data
  Given: I populate DB with data
  When: I open the page
  Then: Page data should match with data from DB
  And: I update each field with some new data
  When: I press save button to save data
  Then: Page data should match with data from DB
```

As you can see, first I populate the database, than I check if it is properly displayed, next I modify it, and check again, so this way I checked two CRUD operations (read and update) in single scenario, but I believe it would be against principles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to combine two CRUD operations in one scenario if your tests are more focussed on integration and end-to-end behaviour rather than unit / component behaviour (which probably is the case).

Of course you should always consider the balance between putting too much in one scenario versus fragmenting a feature into a lot of scenarios. And of course the trade off of asserting more than one thing in a scenario is that it potentially forces you to debug more when a scenario fails. So it's not about principles but rather a conscious choice that you may have to reconsider depending on the speed and stability of your application under test.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ideas, I can share.

```
...
When: I ...
And: I ...
When: ...
...
```

can become

```
...
When: I ...
And: I ...
And: ...
Then: ...
```

even better if you can abstract it to a [declarative business](http://www.marcusoft.net/2013/04/PushTheHowDown.html) function. Which will allow you to see the forest, and not get swamped by the long end-to-end scenarios.

It is good, to think for your BDD journeys from the end-user perspective

```
Given: I populate DB with data
```

is something that happens to the usual user **very** rarely, right? Unless you cover some specific admin/dev case. If, you are using it as precondition, take a look at the xUnit [Fixture Setup patterns](http://xunitpatterns.com/Fixture%20Setup%20Patterns.html). DB validations are a [recommended consideration](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#database-validation), just not at the top most layer of your framework.

And

> greatly cutting execution time

can be achieved via parallel execution of your features/scenarios. Not, by cutting test scenarios. Again, the tradeoff is in favor of the meaningful scenarios.

Comment: Thank you for valuable input.

Comment: more than happy to help